# Timer behaviour after computer sleeps

Tags: delphi, timer, sleep

If I set a timer to fire every 60 minutes, and then put the computer to sleep 30 minutes after the time it last fired, and then wake the computer 20 minutes later, when should the timer fire next?

Seems that 10, 30 or 60 minutes are all possible, but hopefully somebody can tell me so I can save a couple of hours testing it. Also, if it sleeps for over 60 minutes, when will it fire after waking up?

Comment: You might consider detecting when Windows is going to sleep so you can stop your timer and take note of the time, and then detect when Windows wakes up so you note the new time and reset your timer to whatever interval you need.

Comment: You could figure this out yourself with a short test app, with a timer set to fire for a shorter term and manually putting the computer to sleep and waking it up.

Comment: @KenWhite Unfortunately with [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby) that is introduced with newer Windows this becomes a lot more complicated.

Comment: The Windows Task Scheduler is a better place for such long time periods and has settings for each task to select the behaviours. Things like should the computer be woken up to run the task, if the task should be run right away if a run was missed or only on next scheduled time etc. Or implement something similar in your application off a shorter timer - say 5 min that checks for things it should do based on when they were last done and how often they should be executed.